# Laravel app, account swapping when pressing back on browser

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

basically I need some help and I have no idea how to progress or come up with a solution with this issue. This is a similar issue to when you logout of an Laravel app, and press the back button, it will display the information from the cache.

The problem I am getting is, if 2 users share a same computer. At one point the first user gets  page 1 cached (after a form submit they get redirected to page 1). Now, I logout and login using the 2nd user. I go to page 1 then to view the form that was submitted but I then press the back button on the browser. This then leads to page 1 BUT with account 1 on page 1 instead of being account 2 on page 1.

I understand I can remove cache from all pages from my app but the app is currently quite large and relies on the cache in order to load page 1 otherwise I get a out of memory error. I also don't think I can make page 1 efficient enough to load without cache.

Is the only other solution is to have a back button inside the app on every page and disable browsers back button?

I also thought about using an intermediate page between the submit and page1 (therefore in theory would not cache page 1) but this would need to be done throughout the app on any form submit. Is this a possible solution?

Does anyone else have any other solution to this problem? I have the back button currently disabled but I realise it is an inconvenience for users.

Comment: Please provide more details, like, how are users signing in (via Google, Facebook, or local username and password)? Also, are you using PHP or Laravel sessions or you register session data in the database? A bit of code will go a long way.

Comment: Local DB and password. Also are using Laravel sessions and yes, we do register the session data into the DB. Default session table with ID/payload/last_activity columns

I'm not sure which part of the code I would even pull out to demonstrate the this.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have record of the session data inside a table in the database I think a solution could be, to have something like this inside a Controller

```
<?php

public function login(Request $request) {
    //Process the $request data
    $user = //Get user with a model function
    if ( $user ) {
        Auth::login($user);
    }
}

public function logout() {
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
?>
```

In this case your `User` table should have fields with the user session data. If you like to use HTTP sessions then add `Session::flush();`to the `logout` controller function.